# jquery: apply css rule to data attribute added to an element?

Tags: jquery, css

Without using class, how can I apply a simple css rule on a data attribute that gets dynamically added? Here's my current solution with classes, I want to replace this with adding data, and apply the css rule to elements with data attribute 'highlight'. Is this possible? The reason I am doing this is to avoid messing with the underlying DOM data.

```
$(document).on('mouseover',function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(e.target).addClass('highlight');

}).on('mouseout', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(e.target).removeClass('highlight');
});
```

Comment: so you wanna add data "highlight" and a css rule to the hovered element, and then remove them on `mouseout`, am I right?

Comment: @AminJafari yes that is correct, I wasn't sure if this was possible to select elements via data value.

Comment: But Why dont u use class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**jQuery**

```
$(document).on('mouseover',function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(e.target).attr('data-highlight', 'init');

}).on('mouseout', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(e.target).removeAttr('data-highlight');
});
```

**CSS**

```
[data-highlight] {
    background: yellow;
}
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/s8qawkec/).

Comment: can you also use that selector in jquery? `$('*[data-highlight])` ?

Comment: @user299709 Yes, all css selectors exists in jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

if you want what I said in the comments then this is the correct approach:

```
$(document).on('mouseover',function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(e.target).data('highlight',true).css('background-color','#F00'); //the background is an example

}).on('mouseout', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(e.target).data('highlight',false).css('background-color','#CCC');
});
```

Although if you wanna select an element by its data attribute, then you may wanna take a look at this. the code below gets all the `<a>` with the data attribute `highlight` set as `true`:

```
$(document).on('mouseover',$('a').filter(function(){return $(this).data('highlight');}), function(){

}).on('mouseout', $('a').filter(function(){return $(this).data('highlight');}), function(){

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what is needed.

`$(e.target).addClass('highlight').css('display', 'block');`

or could be

`$(e.target).data('class','highlight').css('display', 'block');`

just because you mentioned to add a data attribute